# Isolate rows containing IDs in a column based on another column value, yet keeping all the records of original ID

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-lab

I'd prefer to explain it grafically as it's hard for me to sum it up in the title.

Given a dataframe like this one below:

```
id        type
1         new
2         new
2         new repeater
2         repeater
3         repeater
4         new
4         new repeater
5         new repeater
5         repeater
6         new
```

I would like to filter it so it just returns me the values in the column `id` that appear in `type` at least as `new`, yet once this condition is fulfilled I want the remaining records belonging to this ID to stay in the outcoming DF. In other words, it should look like follows:

```
id        type
1         new
2         new
2         new repeater
2         repeater
4         new
4         new repeater
6         new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) with bollean mask for test first match condition and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['type'].eq('new').groupby(df['id']).cummax()]
print (df)
   id          type
0   1           new
1   2           new
2   2  new repeater
3   2      repeater
5   4           new
6   4  new repeater
9   6           new
```